# SonarQube is unable to analyze file: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

We're facing problems when analyzing one of our Java projects.

The following error is reported:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/jenkins/dev1/Project1/src/com/myproject/dm/voucher/image/TextblockContent.java'
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:93)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:67)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:136)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:129)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:90)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:98)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:185)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:238)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:55)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:274)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:165)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:152)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:118)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:80)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

We execute the analysis using SonarQube Scanner.

SonarQube V5.3 is in use.

Unfortunately I cannot append the file TextblockContent.java to this posting because stackoverflow seems not to offer this feature...

Comment: can you share the whole stacktrace ?

Comment: I've seen this before when sonar had plugins that were buggy or incompatible with the code. It will help if you add the sonar version, version of the plugins and the code of the TextblockContent.java class.